# how to outer join in F# using FLinq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, f#

question pretty much says it all. I have a big flinq query of the following form:

```
for alias1 in table1 do
    for alias2 in table2 do
        if  alias1.Id = alias2.foreignId
```

using this form, how can I do a left outer join between these two tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the `groupJoin` function available in the `Query` module. Here is an example using Northwind with Products as the primary table and Categories as the table with foreign key:

```
open System.Linq

<@ Query.groupJoin 
     db.Products db.Categories 
     (fun p -> p.CategoryID.Value)
     (fun c -> c.CategoryID)
     (fun p cats ->
        // Here we get a sequence of all categories (which may be empty)
        let cat = cats.FirstOrDefault()
        // 'cat' will be either a Category or 'null' value
        p.ProductName, if cat = null then "(none)" else cat.CategoryName) @>
|> query
```

There are definitely nicer ways of expressing this using the `seq { .. }` syntax and by implementing join-like behavior using nested `for` loops. Unfortunatelly, the quotations to LINQ translator will probably not support these. (Personally, I would prefer writing the code using nested `for` and using `if` to check for empty collection).

I was just looking at some improvements in the PowerPack library as part of a contracting work for the F# team, so this will hopefully improve in the future... (but no promises!)

Comment: but how can I use yield here ? I don't want to return "(none)" at all

Comment: I don't think that the `groupJoin` function supports this, but you can always add `|> Seq.filter` to drop all items with `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should create a view in the database that performed the left outer join, and then LINQ over that view.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up created separate queries for each outer join and calling that at certain points when looping through the resultset of the outermost query.