# How to perform left join using SQLProvider in F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to build a query to get the data I need from the Db. Db doesn't have a proper relationship between tables, however to retrieve the data I need I can perform a left join. The problem is that in the documentation it says that leftOuterJoin is not supported (and I would get a notsupported exception is I try to force it). So I wonder if there is another way to perform left join via query expression.

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650890

Comment: See also http://fpish.net/topic/None/56962.  I also found several relevant results at [this Google search.](https://www.google.com/search?q=left+join+in+F%23).

Comment: It seems FSharp.Linq.ComposableQuery could be helpful here: http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Linq.ComposableQuery/QueryExamples.html

Comment: No updates on this?